# Is it possible to tell when a remote bitmessage client is creating new messages?

Tags: anonymity, statistics, bitmessage

[One StackExchange answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26097/is-it-possible-to-encrypt-a-messages-destination-as-well-as-its-content/26121#26121) mentioned bitmessages can be traced, [another](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12975/is-bitmessage-a-mix-network) said it is fully anonymous. The second link seems to cite Wikipedia but a user points out that this anonymous concept doesn't exist in the whitepaper.

My concept is that you could have a tremendous number of bitmessage clients that track the IP address of every client that sends you a message. You keep a log of the IP address and the messages it sent. It seems like you could make a bet of fairly high accuracy whether a client is originating new messages when it's repeatedly the first source of a message you have not seen before.

Is there some aspect of the bitmessage protocol that makes this impossible?

Comment: I just read that anonymous P2P is also exists, the same question could be applied to that I would guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyBitmessage has random forwarding delays, so you won't necessarily receive a message first from the node it originates on. You can increase your anonymity by using a passive node (not accepting connections), and/or by using Tor. Of course, we're trying to improve anonymity even for the rest of the cases.